# count the number of characters in 1 format

Tags: javascript, json

I have a text whose type is string and not array, as shown below:

```
'[123,456],[789],[10]'
```

1. I want the count of number of arrays in this string(in this case it will be 3)
2. I want the number of elements in each array.

I can't use split with commas because there are commas between the numbers in that "array".

And I need to determine the length of those 3 arrays, how do I do that?

**Desired result:**

```
array: 3
length: 2,1,1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add an array in the string so you end up with an actual json array.

Then you can parse the json and count them.

```js
let value = '[' + '[123,456],[789],[10]' + ']';
let json = JSON.parse(value);
json.forEach((item, i) => {
  console.log('length: ' + item.length)
});
console.log(json.length + ' items')
```